# Shell script to check if server was started

Tags: bash, shell

I want to know if my Weblogic server has been started successfully. I get the following string in server_run.log file which shows that server has been started.

```
<20.8.2018 23:25:57 EEST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer><Server started in RUNNING mode>
```

When checking this manually I use following command which tells me that the following string just came in server_run.log file which means server has been started.

```
tail -100f server_run.log | grep 'Server started in RUNNING mode'
```

But I am not able create some if statement using the above command in my shell script. Something like

```
if[tail -100f server_run.log | grep 'Server started in RUNNING mode' ==1 ]
```

Comment: try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-a-shell

Comment: Is it a paid task ?

Comment: ...which is to say, what have you tried? Right now, this reads like "please write script X for me", not "I'm trying to write a script to do X, but this code I wrote expecting it would do Y is instead doing Z; here's how you can see the problem yourself: ..."; the latter is much more likely to be welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a comparison to date with:

```
DATE=`date '+%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S'`
echo $DATE
```

Then compare the date generated to the date from your logs.

If you wanted your system's uptime too you can just use:

```
uptime
```

Comment: Triple-backticks aren't special here -- our markdown isn't GitHub-flavored. Use four-space indents instead.

Comment: BTW, the OP's logs use a different date format -- something closer to `%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S` (though not quite that, as they're removing leading `0`s rather than printing them).